# Local variables and methods with the same name in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, object, methods

```
def gen_times(factor) do
  return Proc.new {|n| n*factor}
end

gen_times.class # ArgumentError 0 for 1
gen_times(3).class # Proc
gen_times = 2
gen_times.class # Fixnum
times3 = gen_times(3) # A normal, working Proc
```

The first gen_times.class gives an ArgumentError, so I assume it returns the class name of gen_times's return value, which is confirmed in the next line.

But then, I assign gen_times, and it becomes a Fixnum. However, I can still use gen_times to return Procs.

I recall that Fixnum objects have immediate values, and that the object itself is used in assignment, rather than a reference to it.

So, is it right to say that gen_times is a Fixnum object that refers to a method?

Comment: Local variables and local functions may live with the same names. To distinguish them explicitly one might use parenthesis.

Comment: I had to read this  a few times to figure out what you are asking.  I think it would be better if you showed the results of running the code inline with the code itself, either as comments, or in the format "I tried this: ... and then this happened: ... so I tried this: ... and then that happened: ..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ruby you can have local variables and methods with the same name. This has some complications for example with setter methods in classes:

```
class Test
  def active
    @active
  end

  def active=(value)
    @active = value
  end

  def make_active
    active = true
  end
end

t1 = Test.new
t1.active = true
t1.active #=> true

t2 = Test.new
t2.make_active
t2.active #=> nil
```

Code for t1 object will return expected result, but code for t2 returns nil, because make_active method is actually creating local variable and not calling active= method. You need to write self.active = true to make this work.

When you write gen_class, ruby tries to access local variable, if it is not defined ruby tries to call method. You can call your method explicit by writing gen_class().